# How can I return the pointer to a specific node in this Binary Tree?

Tags: c, pointers, find, binary-tree, nodes

I have two methods (boolean and pointer return values) for searching for a value in a Binary Tree in C:

```c
bool findInTree(BTNode* bt, char* str) {
    if (bt == NULL) {
        return false;
    }

    if (strcmp(((Course*) (bt->data))->name, str) == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    bool b1 = findInTree(bt->left, str);

    if (b1) {
        return true;
    }

    bool b2 = findInTree(bt->right, str);
    return b2;
}
```

```c
void* findAndReturnInTree(BTNode* bt, char* str) {
    if (bt == NULL) {
        return (void*) NULL;
    }

    if (strcmp(((Course*) (bt->data))->name, str) == 0) {
        return bt->data;
    }

    void* b1 = findAndReturnInTree(bt->left, str);

    if (strcmp(((Course*) (b1))->name, str) == 0) {
        return b1;
    }

    void* b2 = findAndReturnInTree(bt->right, str);
    return b2;
}
```

`findInTree()` works completely fine and is returning the right boolean based on whether that value was in the tree. However, `findAndReturnInTree()` isn't working and I keep getting segmentation faults. I tried to model it off `findInTree()` but returning a pointer instead of a boolean. Btw, I am using `void` pointers as `->data` so that I can use multiple structs and have some sort of generic implementation. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Use a debugger. At a minimum for yourself and for posting on SO you should use the debugger to find out the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault. And then continue to use the debugger to trace the code.

Comment: This looks like a problem: `if (strcmp(((Course*) (b1))->name, str)`. The `b1` value comes from `findAndRetunInTree` which can return NULL. So should check whether `b1` is `NULL` before dereferencing. Again, a debugger would instantly point you to that line and show you that `b1` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b1`, `b2` could have NULL value if a tree node is not found.
After thant `b1->name` could be segmentation fault.

Why don't you add to check NULL at `b1`, `b2`?
C Programmer always check Exception cases.

```c
void* findAndReturnInTree(BTNode* bt, char* str) {
    if (bt == NULL) {
        return (void*) NULL;
    }

    if (strcmp(((Course*) (bt->data))->name, str) == 0) {
        return bt->data;
    }

    void* b1 = findAndReturnInTree(bt->left, str);

    if (b1 == NULL) return findAndReturnInTree(bt->right, str);

    if (strcmp(((Course*) (b1))->name, str) == 0) {
        return b1;
    }

    void* b2 = findAndReturnInTree(bt->right, str);
    return b2;
}
```

Comment: Don't think adding a `return` there is quite right. Still need to continue on to search the `bt->right`